# Searching the First Character of a String to Pull Up Items From An Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, spinner

I have an app I'm working on in Android Studio. I have an array with a list of the 50 states.

The user is able to input one letter of text and then must press "search."
Once they press search, it should display all states beginning with the letter. For instance, if they search "k," they should see Kansas and Kentucky.
These results should be presented in a spinner.

I know I need to use

string_name.charAt(0);

somewhere in my code, but I'm not exactly sure where or what else needs to go with it.

Currently, when I run my app, no matter what letter I search for, the app displays "Alabama" in the spinner and then when you click the drop down for the spinner, it just shows all of the states.

Any help would be appreciated as I am fairly new to Java as well as StackOverflow, so I hope that I presented my question clearly and appropriately. Thank you to anyone who can help.

Here is part of my Java code.

```
    public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
        Button button = (Button) v;
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


        ArrayList states = new ArrayList();
        states.add("Alabama");
        states.add("Alaska");
        states.add("Arizona");
        states.add("Arkansas");
        states.add("California");
        states.add("Colorado");
        states.add("Connecticut");
        states.add("Delaware");
        states.add("Florida");
        states.add("Georgia");
        states.add("Hawaii");
        states.add("Idaho");
        states.add("Illinois");
        states.add("India");
        states.add("Iowa");
        states.add("Kansas");
        states.add("Kentucky");
        states.add("Louisiana");
        states.add("Maine");
        states.add("Maryland");
        states.add("Massachusetts");
        states.add("Michigan");
        states.add("Minnesota");
        states.add("Mississippi");
        states.add("Missouri");
        states.add("Montana");
        states.add("Nebraska");
        states.add("Nevada");
        states.add("New Hampshire");
        states.add("New Jersey");
        states.add("New Mexico");
        states.add("New York");
        states.add("North Carolina");
        states.add("North Dakota");
        states.add("Ohio");
        states.add("Oklahoma");
        states.add("Oregon");
        states.add("Pennsylvania");
        states.add("Rhode Island");
        states.add("South Carolina");
        states.add("South Dakota");
        states.add("Tennessee");
        states.add("Texas");
        states.add("Utah");
        states.add("Vermont");
        states.add("Virginia");
        states.add("Washington");
        states.add("West Virginia");
        states.add("Wisconsin");
        states.add("Wyoming");

        final
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed you listed "India" instead of "Indiana".

Comment: Thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked, at least you need to get the value in the input box, then choose what to add to that arrayList according to the first letter.

I didn't see your code getting the input text.

Answer (score 0):

well you can also make a substring of the state string in a for loop and test with the input.The substring works with a start and end variable like 
Result=states.substring(0,1), as this it will keep only the first letter